# typeahead.js not working, no errors in console either

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I can't understand why this isn't working. There are no errors it just doesn't display my options.

```
<input id="hello" class="form-control" type="text">

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

var subjects = ['PHP', 'MySQL', 'SQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'HTML', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'CSS3', 'JSON'];
$('#hello').typeahead({ source: subjects })
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8naL335a/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the fiddle :

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/413dg2o2/][1]
```

I have made some changes in the html and javascript file.Please check the url https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ for more details.